# Create content after editing other content-type

Tags: 8, entities, hooks

I have a certain content-type B with an entity reference to items of content-type A.

I'm trying to programmatically create a content-type B node when a bool field in content-type A is set to `true`, whether during creation of content-type A or update/editing of content-type A.

Something like this story:

> When user creates or edits a `news` content (ie, sets the `push_to_slider` field as `true`), create a `slide` content if it doesn't exist. If the user sets the field as `false`, delete the `slide` content.

I've been exploring how to do this, and I found out about `hook_entity_presave`. So, right now, I'm able to check what was edited in the content-type A form, and if it is being created or updated.

My questions are:

- **How can I find out the ID of the content-type A node?** I need to know it so I can pass it along when I `getStorage('type-B')->create(array)`. This might be available when *editing* a A-type node, but not when *inserting* it, at least not in `hook_entity_presave`. As far as I can tell, I might be doing this in the wrong place as this hook operates **before** the DB insertion, is this correct? As such I think I wouldn't have access to an ID at this point. What could be the alternative?
- Also, **how can I find out if a B-type content already exists referencing the A-type node I'm working with?** I intend to use that to find out if what I need to delete in case the option in the form is set to `false`.

Hope this makes sense. If not, let me know and I'll try to clarify. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: I used rules for this and in the rules engine you directly have the nodeid available. . In rules there is also the possibility to implement php so maybe this is a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to document what I learned during the process of trying to figure out how D8 works (namely, 8.1.x, which is the version I'm working with), in order to find a solution to my problem.

So, the first thing I had to find out was where I had to produce the changes I needed. I though of [hook_entity_presave](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_presave/8.1.x) but it wasn't the way to go because I would need info on nodes that might not exist at the time that hook would be called. I found out there are 2 hooks used when [inserting](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_insert/8.1.x) or [updating](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_update/8.1.x) nodes. As both of my entities are nodes, this is where the magic happens each time you edit or create new content nodes - in my case, both the A and B types mentioned in the question.

Each of these functions has an `$entity` parameter variable with methods available for pretty much everything you might need.

For instance, if you need to know which content-type the `$entity` represents in a given call to these hooks you can simply call its [bundle()](https://www.drupal.org/node/2143499) method:

```
$node_content_type = $entity->bundle();
```

In many cases, the node's value for fields will be available like this:

```
$title_field_value = $entity->title->value;
```

Other times, like this:

```
$custom_field_value = $entity->toArray()['field_custom_field_name'][0]['value'];
```

Particularly, if you need the `id` for a node, you can simply:

```
$node_id = $entity->id();
```

But maybe most importantly, I found out about Drupal 8's [entityQuery](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3AentityQuery/8.1.x) function, and [how to use it](https://www.sitepoint.com/drupal-8-version-entityfieldquery/). In my scenario, I used it to check for the existence of certain node `id` to programmatically produce some behavior.

This takes me to the node [methods](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/group/entity_api/8.1.x) I was looking for:

- **Node::load($id)**: when you already have an ID (for instance as a result of the query), and want to load the entire node for some operation on its values;
- **Node::create(array)**: you can *create* a new node with this method by passing it an array of the values you want/need. Needs to be `save()`'d after creation;
- **Node::delete()**: deletes the node. **DOES NOT** need `save()`;
- **Node->set(field, value)**: after you `load()` a node, you can use this method to set (ie, update) its values. Also needs `save()` when done.

On a final notice, remember that when using `save()`you will always go through either the `insert` or `update` hooks, if you either create a new node or update it, respectively. Remember this *especially* if you create a new node when updating another one - I did it wrong and got caught in a loop between inserting and updating nodes that generated heaps of repeated content in my D8 install (oops!...).

**DISCLAIMER:** I wrote this answer to my own question because I felt the need to clarify many of these aspects for someone that might have a similar issue. I also +1'd @ssibal's answer because it pointed me to the need of using `entityQuery`. I think D8's documentation is still very sparse/inconsistent and I had to scavenge lots of sources to figure this out. Hope it helps anyone.

Answer (score 1):

**How can I find out the ID of the content-type A node?**

You should use devel module's kint function to get all available methods of an object, and you could easy find out, that it's: $node_object->id();

**how can I find out if a B-type content already exists referencing the A-type node I'm working with?**

You will write a Database service query (not pure sql query), where you will have two important condition:

- the node type must be B
- it's reference field contains the id of the A content.

You will of course have to use table joins. To better understand the schema representation of your content types, I suggest you do use phpmyadmin parallel.